# Keyboard animation is not smooth

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement a very smooth keyboard animation that is as smooth a tik tok or instagram's. The problem I am having is that when the textfield is tapped, the keyboard appears, then shortly after the widgets in the AnimatedPadding() appear. When the textfield is also dismissed, it's as if the widgets in the AnimatedPadding() goes down step by step after the keyboard has been dismissed. I've tried many things to have the AnimatedPadding() be as smooth as possible when the keyboard comes on and off, but so far nothining better. Thanks in advance for your help?

Here's my code:

Widget showContent()
{
return Column(

```
   children: [

     Expanded(child: SizedBox()),  ///some content to show

     AnimatedPadding(

       padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
       duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 00),  /// I made the duration to be zero. Still, it appears shortly after the system's keyboard is already up.
       curve: Curves.decelerate,
       child: Row(
         children: [
           Expanded(
             child: Padding(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
               child: Container(

                 height: 40,

                 //height: 40,
                 width: width * 0.95,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                   border: Border.all(
                     width: 1,
                     color: Colors.red,
                   ),
                 ),
                 child: Padding(
                     padding:   EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, bottom: height*0.005),
                     child:




                         GestureDetector(
                           key: openingPage.gesturedetectorKey,
                           //onTap: somefunction,
                           child: TextField(

                             enabled: true,

                             cursorColor: Colors.black38,
                             style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),

                             controller: Controller,
                             decoration:  InputDecoration(
                               hintText: 'write something',

                               hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 15),
                               border: InputBorder.none,
                             ),

                           ),
                         ),


                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),

           Icon(Icons.arrow_upward)

         ],
       ),
     )

     // },
     //  );
     //  },
     //  ),


   ],
 );
```

}